# How to trigger function from background script to script in web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am currently writing a chrome extension. I now want to call a function inside of a script which is loaded from a web page.

I already tried to send a simple message from background.js to my web page.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ test: 'hello' }, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Throws error: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

On my web page script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function (callback) {
    console.log(callback);
});
```

Throws error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined"

How do I send messages from my background.js to someWebPageScript.js?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First question: Is 'someWebPageScript.js' your 'content.js' script, or something declared in your manifest(which could also be helpful to see)?

If so, and you're attempting to pass a message from your background script to your content script, you may want to carefully read the Chrome Message Passing docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).  Passing a message TO a content script looks more like:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

And the receiving end(in the content script) needs to look more like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(sender.tab ?
              "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
              "from the extension");
  if (request.greeting == "hello")
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

The `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` listener that you're using is intended for receiving messages from other extensions.

Hope this helps.
-brent